# pywin32 win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages() placement

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I'm attempting to write some python code to detect a monitor changed event in Windows; I'm using pywin32, largely based around code from the [pywin32 example](http://pywin32.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pywin32/pywin32/win32/Demos/win32gui_devicenotify.py?revision=1.2&view=markup). It appears that the placement of `PumpWaitingMessages` makes a difference; the code below does detect a monitor change (i.e. `OnDeviceChange` gets run) but the `lp` argument is 0, so I can't get any useful info from it (i.e. the monitor identifier).

```
class Foo(QObject):    
    def OnDeviceChange(self, hwnd, msg, wp, lp):
        info = win32gui_struct.UnpackDEV_BROADCAST(lp)
        print("Device change notification:", wp, str(info))  #
        return True

    def __init__(self):
        wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        wc.lpszClassName = 'test_devicenotify'
        wc.style = win32con.CS_GLOBALCLASS|win32con.CS_VREDRAW | win32con.CS_HREDRAW
        wc.hbrBackground = win32con.COLOR_WINDOW + 1
        wc.lpfnWndProc = {win32con.WM_DEVICECHANGE: self.OnDeviceChange}
        class_atom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)
        hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,
            'Waiting for Monitor Change',
            # no need for it to be visible.
            win32con.WS_CAPTION,
            100, 100, 900, 900, 0, 0, 0, None)
        filter = win32gui_struct.PackDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE(
                                            GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR)
        hdev = win32gui.RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, filter,
                                                   win32con.DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)


f = Foo()
while True:
    win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

However, if I move the `while True` loop from the very end of the code to the end of the `__init__` method, then the `lp` argument is populated, and I can get the info I want.

Any ideas why the placement of the while loop would make a difference?

Comment: Hmm; looking at the docs for PumpWaitingMessages, it seems it works on the current thread; I'm guessing that this is where the problem may lie.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I do see that [you are registering the window class globally](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873), which is probably not what you want to do. You may also want to make the window message-only by passing `HWND_MESSAGE` as the parent window parameter to `CreateWindow()`, but I'm not sure if that will make your window ineligible for device notifications or not.

Comment: I see that `Foo` extends `QObject`. Are you using _PyQt_ as well? If yes, since _Qt_ has its own windows handling mechanism, is it OK to mix that with plain _WinAPI_'s?

Comment: I'm using both pyqt and pywin32; the device changed event isn't exposed by pyqt.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's part of the borrowed code, I'm going to start with a recommendation of renaming variable `filter` to something else, because it's shadowing [[Python]: **filter**(*function, iterable*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) (didn't change myself when I edited the post since I couldn't post a comment specifying why I've done it). Also, you might want to add the missing pieces to have a working code snippet: imports, definitions (e.g. `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR`, I browsed *Ioevent.h*, and I couldn't find neither *USB* nor display related *GUID*s)

I suspected 2 things that might be held accountable for this behavior:

- Mixing *PyQt* (which has its own windows handling) with plain *WinAPI* (as I wrote in my comment), and the possibility that one of the 2 might step on the other's toes
- *Python* scopes ([[Python]:
  Execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html))

I didn't want to install *PyQt*, so I started exploring the other possibility. I was able to reproduce the same behavior with the original code (that you started from). The problem was that at the end of `TestDeviceNotifications`, `hdev` (returned by `RegisterDeviceNotification`), was going out of scope.

The same thing happens here: after exiting `__init__`, (when messages will start to be sent to the window) `hdev` will be an invalid handle. To correct this, make it *global*:

- declare it at module level (before `Foo`) like: `hdev = None`
- instruct `__init__` to operate on the global variable instead of creating a new local one with the same name. Somewhere in `__init__`, **before** `hdev = win32gui.RegisterDeviceNotification` add `global hdev`, and it will be persistent

**Note(s)**:

- Typically, all created resources should be freed when they're no longer needed. This is what you should do with `wc` and `hwnd`. Regarding `hdev`, [[MSDN]: RegisterDeviceNotification function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't mention anything about calling `CloseHandle` (or smth similar) upon it, so I think, it's good

Comment: Does this answer your question?